# symmetric group - elements with an specific order

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I've got H = <(2 1 3 4 5 6)(7 8 10 9)> a subgroup of the symmetric group S_10 , and I have to calculate all the elements of H which have got order 6

---

If I'm not wrong, H can be written like this: H={b^i a^i | i {0,1,2,3} and j {0,1,2,3,4,5}}
 I've defined: a=(1 3 4 5 6 2) and b=(7 8 10 9)
I've calculated all the elements:
b^0 a^0
b^0 a^1
b^0 a^2
.
.
.
b^3 a^4
b^3 a^5

And what I've obtained is that the elements of order 6 are:
b^0 a^1 = (1 3 4 5 6 2)
b^0 a^5 = (1 2 6 5 4 3)
b^2 a^1 = (7 10)(8 9)(1 3 4 5 6 2)
b^2 a^2 = (7 10)(8 9)(1 4 6)(2 3 5)
b^2 a^3 = (7 10)(8 9)(1 5)(2 4)(3 6)
b^2 a^4 = (7 10)(8 9)(164)(253)
b^2 a^5 = (7 10)(8 9)(1 2 6 5 4 3)

But I'm not sure this is OK... Anyway, I would like to know a shorter way to find the elements of order 6 without calculating all the elements of H (if it's possible).

Comment: So there is only 1 element of order 6 in H?

Comment: No, there is a unique subgroup of order $6$. That is not the same. This subgroup has $2$ elements of order $6$.

Comment: Oh OK, but how can I know which are those 2 elements?

Comment: I think that I don't really understand of which type are the elements of H

Comment: Oh, that's easy. Write $\sigma=(2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6)(7, 8, 10, 9)$. Then $H=\langle \sigma\rangle=\{\sigma^0,\sigma^1, \ldots ,\sigma^{11}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the cycle are disjoint they commute, so the order of the element $\sigma = \sigma_{1}\cdot \sigma_{2} = lcm(o(\sigma_{1}),o(\sigma_{2}))$, where $\sigma_{1} = (2\hspace{0.1cm} 1\hspace{0.1cm} 3 \hspace{0.1cm}4\hspace{0.1cm} 5 \hspace{0.1cm}6), \sigma_{2} = (7 \hspace{0.1cm} 8 \hspace{0.1cm} 10 \hspace{0.1cm}9)$. Since $o(\sigma_{2}) = 6, o(\sigma_{1}) = 4$ we have that $o(H) = o(\langle \sigma \rangle) = o(\sigma) = 12$, hence $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12}$, cyclic.

It follows that for each divisor $n$ of $12$ there are exatcly $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$, where $\phi$ denotes the Euler function.

Edit : Since you have to count the elements when $n = 6$, if you know that there are $\phi(6) = 2$ such elements of order $6$ you know even which, since there are $2$ obvious choices for it, which are $\sigma^{2} = (2\hspace{0.1cm}3\hspace{0.1cm}5)(1\hspace{0.1cm}4\hspace{0.1cm}6)(7\hspace{0.1cm}10)(8\hspace{0.1cm}9)$ and its inverse.

Comment: So like I want to know the elements of order 6 and the Euler function of 6 is 2, I conclude that there are only 2 elements of order 6 in H, am I right?

Comment: @Maialen Yes you are right. Notice that this only works since the subgroup is cyclic. Try to think for example to the number of transposition in $S_{3}$

Comment: Oh thanks! But how can I know which are those 2 elements of order 6?

Comment: @Maialen In general you can't. In this case you are seeking for elements of order six and since there are two, once noticed that the square of $\sigma$ works, the other one is free since $\sigma$ is not the inverse of itself. Of course consideration about the cycle structure can be done in order to semplify the calculus.

Comment: And the inverse is (1 6 4)(2 5 3)(7 10)(8 9) right?

Comment: @Maialen Yes exactly, you just have to invert the $3$-cycles

Comment: And I've got other question, How can I know if the (7 8)H and (8 10 9)H are equal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107622/discussion-between-jacopoburelli-and-maialen).